# GroupBy Power Query result not matching with pandas.groupby result?

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, grouping, powerquery

I'm trying to "port" a row grouping transformation from PowerQuery to Python. In PowerQuery, the query looks something like this:

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Count"}),
```

In python, I've tried to use something like

```
df1 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]).apply(lambda x:x)
```

However, the results come out very differently. Note that there are more columns outside the groupby statement. Should I select only the columns I need first and then perform the grouping, or should I group and then select the columns?

There is also a summation column that was added afterwards in the PowerQuery, but I've added it earlier in the steps with the python code. I imagine you would exclude that column in the grouping.

It would also be helpful if someone could explain what exactly is happening when you group my multiple columns. And maybe why the two methods behave differently. Is it similar to selecting only those columns and removing duplicate rows?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the M expression in pandas is,

```
Table.Group(
    Source,
    {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"},
    {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}
)
```

```py
df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]) \
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([len(x)], index=["Count"]))
```

While `Table.Group()` in M takes list of column names and functions that generate the aggregated column values, pandas `GroupBy.apply()` takes a function that returns a Series containing aggregated column values.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do it without creating the count column? In PowerQuery, it didn't seem possible so the original creator just removed the column afterwards. Is there a reason why we are forced to create a new aggregated column in order for the rest of the columns to group?

Comment: It's super easy. `df[["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]].drop_duplicates()`. Also possible in PowerQuery `Table.Distinct(Table.SelectColumns(Source, {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"}))`.

Comment: So by adding the `index=["Count"]` portion, that makes it so that only "Count" is the lifted as a column, while the column names have been demoted as keys? I'm sorry if I'm using incorrect terminology.

And for the other suggestion, I've tried that as well and the results don't come out as expected either. It seems to be keeping too many records. Perhaps I'm just doing something incorrectly, but I'm not sure of the best way to troubleshoot what's happening in the data.

Comment: Can you give more info to reproduce the problem? What is your data frame look like, and how do you think the result of `drop_duplicates()` is not correct?

Comment: hmm. I don't know how to explain this without using too much identifiable data... I did manage to do something a little bit different with the aggregation since I needed a summation column anyways later on in the process. I did: `df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'],as_index=False)[['col5']].sum()` I'm building visualisations on the data in Power BI, and when I compare the total sum of 'col5' using each of the methods, they are off by about 8k. That's a significant number

Comment: I figured out the difference. Groupby in pandas will drop any rows if any of the columns you're grouping by has null values in that row. PowerBI does not do this. To get around it, I changed the nulls to empty strings.